# How to count and export duplicate values (example attached)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, postgresql, r

I have been scratching my head trying to figure out how to produce a statistic table as formulated in the attached picture:

[image: This is a guide to help understand what my data looks like]

I have about 670k objects (`Item_id`) divided between around 1000 IDs (`FID`) and I need to produce a table to show for each ID how many objects appear once, twice, three times, four times, five times or six times or great.

What I have is:

```
FID Item_ID
1 TH22
1 Th2
1 Th9
1 TH22
2 TH3
2 TH22
2 TH99
```

So at the end (this very small example) it sould look like:

```
ID Once Twice Three times Four Times Five Times Six Times or greater

1 2 1 0 0 0 0
2 3 0 0 0 0 0
```

I think Excel can do this but it might be I need to use R or SQL. But I would really appreciate any ideas and some instructions of how to go about producing this table.

I wish everyone well

Answer (score 0):

Using only formulas, the only thing I came near solution is as below:
[image: EXCEL SHEET EXAMPLE]

Assuming the data is as in the example, at `F2` cell put the below formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$1001=$E2)*(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$1001,$E2,$C$2:$C$1001,$C$2:$C$1001)=F$1)/F$1)
```

The header `F:K` are the occurrences for 1,2...6 times.
This formula does not meet your requirements for 6 or greater. All occurrences should be stated, so if there will be items that occur more than 6 times, you should put that in the table header, so you will have to make it longer by adding the numbers 7,8,9... etc... Since I am dividing the number of found items with occurrences to find the exact number of items, it is not possible (at least I think so for the moment) to find items with 6 or greater. I need to explicitly state this number.

I also added totals and a check control so there will be no mistakes. The check cell should be 0. The total of each column will be, for example for column F -> `sum(F2:F11)*F1` and for others just drag the formula. The check will substract total of all columns from count of item_ID.

Comment: You may put the occurrences of 6,7,8,9, etc... in another place in worksheet, and then at column 6 or greater, you may just make a sum of them... Adding a comment for the moment since I dont have time to make another example at the answer, but I think it will work out. Will edit tomorrow after back from work

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  I feel like you cracked it, but for some reason I still cant get it to work.  I when entering the code I get an error message.  I only have a German language version of Excel (English function names don't work).  But even so I still get an error message.

(Edit because i pressed enter without shift)

Did you really mean add the code at F1? Isn't it at F2?

Comment: https://imgur.com/U1Vun1G

Comment: i posted a  imgur link to my screenshot.  https://imgur.com/U1Vun1G

Comment: Please to paste the formula as I am not able to see it clearly

Comment: =SUMMENPRODUKT(($B$2:$B$1001=$E2)*(ZÄHLENWENNS($B$2:$B$1001,$E2,$C$2:$C$1001,$C$2:$C$1001)=F$1)/F$1)

Comment: Can you try to put the two functions in different cells to see which is causing the error: ZÄHLENWENNS($B$2:$B$1001,$E2,$C$2:$C$1001,$C$2:$C$1001) and the other function SUMMENPRODUKT($B$2:$B$1001=$E2)*(1/F$1)

Comment: The first function causes the error. (ZÄHLENWENN).

Thank you so much for this.

Comment: I was reading the documentation for Zahlenwenns function and it requires to use ";" instead of "," as a delimiter. Try making this modification for that function. So for german language it seems excel uses semicolon for seperators

Comment: That's brillitant!  Thank you so much.  You've made my day! I find coding so interesting but it's so difficult to get into. Professionals like yourself make it much easier.